# in what language should the API be written?

Tags: database, api, programming-languages

We want to implement an API, we have a database located on a central server, and a network of many computers.
On these computers, several local programs will be developed in the future using different programming languages, some in java, some in perl, C++, ... etc.

These local programs should be able to access the API functions and interact with the database.
So in what language should the API be written ? so that it would be binding to the other languages. Is there any specific architecture that should be implemented ?
Is there any link that would provide useful information about this ?

Comment: I build my API with lego bricks... No but really, I usually go with a REST API, potentially using JSON, which is fairly well supported (http://www.json.org/). Even if you're using a language that doesn't support it, the syntax is fairly easy to parse imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the API is pure database access, then a REST web service is a reasonable choice. It allows a (reasonably) easy interface from almost any language, and allows you to choose whatever language you feel is best for writing the actual web service. However, in doing it this way, you're paying the cost of an extra network call per API call. If you put the web service on the same host (or local network) as the database, you can minimize the cost of the network call from the web service to the database, which mitigates the cost of the extra call to the API.

If the API has business logic in it, there's two via approaches...

You can write the API as a library that can be used from multiple languages. C is a good choice for this because most languages can link C libraries, but the languages you expect to use it from can have a large impact, too. For example, if you know it's always going to be used by a language hosted on the JVM, the any JVM language it probably a reasonably good choice.

Another choice is to use a hybrid of the two. A REST API for database access, plus a business layer library written in multiple languages. The idea being that you have business logic on the application end, but it's simple enough that you can write a "client library" in multiple languages that knows how to call out to the REST API and then apply business logic to the results it gets back. Assuming the business logic isn't too complex (ie, limited to ways to merge/view the database data), then this isn't a bad solution.

The benefit is that it should be relatively easy to supply one "default" library that can be used by many languages, plus other language specific versions of the library where you have time available to implement them. For cases where figuring out what calls need to be made to the database, and how to combine the results, can be complicated, I find this to be a reasonably good solution.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer ! so I can conclude from this that I should be using REST, since the API has only to access the database, (store/retreive data) from the various computers on the network.

Answer (score 2):

I would resort to webservices. Doesn't matter what language you use as long as you have a framework to interact with webservices you are good. Depending on your needs you could expose a simple REST API or go all the way with SOAP/WSDL and the likes.

Comment: Maybe some OData if you're into that kind of thing.